# Progressive Image Loading on Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, loading, partial

I have a ViewPager that I'm using to page through several ImageViews (around 1000) which each load a full-screen Bitmap. I'm subsampling the images using `options.inSampleSize` and using a memcache for performance but this is still not fast enough. What I'm trying to avoid is the user seeing blank ImageViews when they page through the views quickly.

I'm wondering if there is a way to serve a partially rendered image (or low quality) while the requested image loads.

I've noticed the Android gallery incorporates something like this (especially noticeable when zooming in and out, loading looks similar to loading of a progressive JPEG on the web), but I haven't been able to find any related information.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not currently provide a way to get intermediate images during decoding (e.g. a progressive JPEG).  You only get one final image.

You are already using inSampleSize to get more coarse versions of the image.  This makes the decode hopefully quicker, although there are no time guarantees: it uses libjpeg under the hood.  Have you measured how long each image decode takes?  Have you tried setting inPreferQualityOverSpeed to false?  Are you reusing the same bitmap (also may speed up decode).  You can also check if inSampleSize makes a different in speed.

In any case, any work of getting low-quality images quickly gets lost if you then want a more detailed version of the same image, as you have to start the decode from the beginning.  Therefore, you want to limit decoding to the visible images plus its near neighbors so that you can scroll without blank images.

Comment: While you are correct that it doesn't do it by default, there are ways to perform partial decoding of images. It's definitely not faster than just loading the full image, though. @Cam mentions the Gallery application - it loads a smaller, previously resized version of the image from MediaStore first.